# If with multiple ands and mid function

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask you for help. I'm trying towrite a code that changes text into cells each of them has only one sentence.
If letter1= ".", letter2=""", letter3 = " ", letter4= A then it should take the sentence and paste it to the another sheet's corresponding cell.

Excemple sentence = Player." And I thought, "Well, what's the struggle.
first sentence should be  = Player." 
second sentence should be   = And I thought, "Well, what's the struggle.

Here is code :

```
    Sub Subtitles()
    
    Dim lr As Double 'lastrow
    Dim lc As Byte 'last column
    Dim s As Byte 'looping in columns
    Dim r As Double 'looping in rows
    Dim c As Double 'looping in a cell
    Dim k As Double 'pasting sheet row counter
    Dim hourstring As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim range_sentence As String
    Dim sentence As String
    Dim letter1 As String
    Dim letter2 As String
    Dim letter3 As String
    Dim letter4 As String
    
    lr = MainSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = MainSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'change ...
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lr, lc)).Select
    Selection.Replace What:="...", Replacement:="qwertyytrewq", Lookat:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    
    
    Set ws = Sheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet, After:=Application.ActiveSheet)
    
    s = 1
    Do While s < lc + 1
    k = 3
    
    For r = 1 To lr
    
        If MainSheet.Cells(r, s).NumberFormat = "h:mm" Then
            hourstring = Format(MainSheet.Cells(r, s), "h:mm")
            sentence = "[" & hourstring & "]  "
            
            r = r + 1
        End If
        
        range_sentence = MainSheet.Cells(r, s).Value
        
        
        For c = 1 To VBA.Len(range_sentence)
            
            letter1 = VBA.Mid(range_sentence, c, 1)
            letter2 = VBA.Mid(range_sentence, c + 1, 1)
            letter3 = VBA.Mid(range_sentence, c + 2, 1)
            letter4 = VBA.Mid(range_sentence, c + 3, 1)
    
    
            If letter1 = "." And letter2 = Chr(34) And letter3 = " " And letter4 = LCase(letter4) Then
                sentence = sentence + letter1 + letter2 + letter3 + letter4
                c = c + 3
    
            **ElseIf letter1 = "." And letter2 = Chr(34) And letter3 = " " And letter4 = UCase(letter4) Then**
                ws.Cells(k, s).Value = sentence + letter1 + letter2 + letter3
                c = c + 2
                k = k + 1
                sentence = ""

Example sentence:
Player." And I thought, "Well, what's the struggle?"

In this sentence, at frist point ".", 
letter1 = ".", letter2 = chr(32), letter3 = " ", letter4 is upper case, but first elseif block doesnt work. I couldnt find why. I can paste whole code if you want.

Many thanks in advance.
```

Comment: I must confess that I do not understand too much from your question. There is a lot of code not connected to the question expressed in words, like you try to confuse us un purpose... So, what would you like to accomplish? Which to be the splitting rule? If this would be the sentence: "Player." And I thought, "Well, what's the struggle.", how many sentances should result by splitting it? Two, or three? Should the double quotes be the separation delimiter? If not, based on what do you like to split it?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off addressing this problem using the SPLIT function.

Start by splitting on full stops into an array:

```
Dim sSentences() As String
sSentences = range_sentence(".")
```

Then do any additional processing you require and iterate the array to paste the individual values into your cells:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(sSentences) To UBound(sSentences)
    ...do what you need to do with... sSentences(i)
Next
```

Comment: I am trying to take texts on internet and arrange them sentece by sentece. I think I found the problem. But I don2t know how to solve it.
When I take texts on internet ( For example this videos english subtitles : https://www.ted.com/talks/brene_brown_the_power_of_vulnerability/transcript?language=tr#t-8217)

When I copy it and paste it, its spaces after dots are not regular spaces in excel. When i try to replace all spaces into something else, these spaces stays the same. I thought it could be about ascii characters but I couldn't find the reason.

Comment: Debug what the non-standard space characters are using Asc and then search for them using Chr.